# Split string into multiple parts based on its offset value

Tags: javascript, typescript

Below is the text, I wanted to break down into multiple parts, based on the `offset` & `length`.

> Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC?
>   Please visit our customer support page.

Below is the function to extract the text based based on it's `offset` & `length`.

```
  let offset = '83';
  let length = '16';   

  getText(offset, length, text: string) {
    return text.substr(offset, length);
  }
```

The above function returns, `customer support`.

**So that actual problem**

I've to split the `before` & `after` text of the string. Something like below eg

text1: Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our

text2: customer support

text3: page

Can can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can base this problem on a related one, `breakAt` which splits a string at a number of cut points.  That can be built on something that turns a list into a list of its contiguous pairs.  (That is, `[2, 3, 5, 7] => [[2, 3], [3, 5], [5, 7]]`.) Both of these functions could have other reasonable uses in your application.

Here's an implementation built that way:

```js
const intoPairs = xs => xs.slice(1).map((x, i) => [xs[i], x])
const breakAt = (places, str) => intoPairs([0, ...places, str.length]).map(
  ([a, b]) => str.substring(a, b)
)
const getText = (offset, length, str) => breakAt([offset, offset+ length], str)

const str = "Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our customer support page."
console.log(getText(83, 16, str))
```

It's not quite clear to me what your preferred output format is.  This just generates an array containing the before, within, and after texts, based upon your `offset`, `length`, and `str`.

---

### Update

A follow-up comment asked about breaking out multiple sub-strings.  That was exactly what this slight generalization had been intended to allow.  This version builds on `breakAt` to write a new function which accepts multiple `offset`/`length` pairs in order to break the word down further.  It doesn't try to deal with the possibility of overlaps; that would be the lookout of the caller.  It does, however sort those pairs so that you don't have to supply them in order.

```js
const intoPairs = xs => xs.slice(1).map((x, i) => [xs[i], x])
const breakAt = (places, str) => intoPairs([0, ...places, str.length]).map(
  ([a, b]) => str.substring(a, b)
)
const breakWhere = (words, str) => breakAt(
  words.slice(0).sort(({offset: o1}, {offset: o2}) => o1 - o2).reduce(
    (a, {offset, length}) => [...a, offset, offset + length],
    []
  ),
  str
)

const str = "Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our customer support page."

console.log(breakWhere([
  {offset: 83, length: 16}, // "customer support"
  {offset: 12, length: 9},  // "questions"
  {offset: 25, length: 8},  // "comments"
], str))
```

The `slice` call is simply to avoid mutating the list of `offset/length` pairs.  You can drop it if that's not a concern.

### Another Update

Another followup comment (last one for this question, @stacks; next time start a new question!) asked how to format the output into nodes that tracked plain versus link text.  This is a fairly naive version of that:

```js
const intoPairs = xs => xs.slice(1).map((x, i) => [xs[i], x])
const breakAt = (places, str) => intoPairs([0, ...places, str.length]).map(
  ([a, b]) => str.substring(a, b)
)
const breakWhere = (words, str) => breakAt(
  words.reduce((a, {offset, length}) => [...a, offset, offset + length], []),
  str
)

const createNodes = (links, str) => {
  const sortedLinks = links.slice(0).sort(({offset: o1}, {offset: o2}) => o1 - o2)

  return breakWhere(sortedLinks, str).map((s, i) => i % 2 == 0 
    ? {data: s, type: 'text'}
    : {data: s, type: 'link', path: sortedLinks[(i - 1) / 2].path}
  ).filter(({data}) => data.length > 0)
}

const str = "Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our customer support page."

const links = [
//  {offset: 0, length: 6, path: '/path/to/doYou'},
  {offset: 83, length: 16, path: '/path/to/custSupport'},
  {offset: 12, length: 9, path:  'path/to/questions'},
  {offset: 25, length: 8, path:  'path/to/comments'},
]


console.log(createNodes(links, str))
```

This wraps a simplified version of the earlier call into one that maps alternate strings to `type: 'text'` and `type: 'link'` objects, each with a `data` property.  The links also are given a `path`.  That `path` may not work with your data, and you could just skip it in the code.

The `filter` call at the end is to remove potentially empty text nodes.  If two links abut, or if there is one at the beginning or end of the string, then there would be an empty node.  You can see this by uncommenting the extra `link`.  If you remove the `filter` call, this would leave an initial empty text node, probably not what's wanted.

I call this version naive because it does not handle several possibilities, most importantly overlapping sections.  That seems a fair bit more difficult, and it might never be necessary for your project.

### Note

An important thing about this approach is that it's *layered*.  Instead of trying to write a function that does everything that's needed in one go, we build up helper functions.  `intoPairs` and `breakAt` both might be useful on their own.  `breakWhere` and `createNodes` are probably more specific to this problem.  I built `createNodes` having already created `breakWhere`.  It was straightforward to layer the new function on top of the old.

In other words, the very design incorporates some of the history of changing requirements.  It is probably sub-optimal in terms of performance, not because of any serious flaws but only because it was not initially created with the final requirements in mind.  Sometimes it's worth going back an rethinking such code, but it's not always important.  You would have to decide if the additional loops this uses are a serious concern to your application, or if you just want code that is less layered.

Comment: Thanks, What if I have multiple offset values for the same string ? how can this be achieved ?

Comment: You're solutions is just perfect, But only issue is, It very hard to change the output as object. like something like this `[{
    data: 'Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our',
    type: 'text'
  },
  {
    data: 'customer support',
    type: 'link'
  },
  {
    data: 'page.',
    type: 'text'
  }]`

Comment: @stacks: Updated with another version.  Any further changes should probably involve a new question.

Comment: I've created a new question as suggested, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55001801/assigning-dynamic-types-to-string/55003182#55003182

Answer (score 0):

You may want to modify this to trim unwanted spaces and/or punctuation.

```js
let text = 'Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our customer support page.'

let offset = 83;
let length = 16;

function getText(offset, length, text) {
    return { text1: text, text2: text.substr(offset, length), text3: text.substr(offset + length) };
}

let split = getText(offset, length, text);
console.log(split)
```

Comment: Don't you need to call `text.substr(0, offset)` for `text1`?

Comment: Text 1 is wrong, it should be like this `Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our`

Comment: It currently prints like `"text1": "Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our customer support page."` which is wrong