# Assigning dynamic types to string

Tags: javascript, typescript

Based on the below `data` I need to break down the text on its `offset` & `length` value.

```
const data = {
  "text": "This is sample text",
  "range": [{
    "type": "LINK",
    "offset": 0,
    "length": 16,
    "data": {
      "target": "_self",
      "url": "/index.htm"
    }
  }]
}
```

With the below snippet, I could break down the text at any specific point.

**So What's the problem ?**

I wanted to breakdown the text in the below format, With dynamic type assigned to it.

**How types will be assigned ?**

If no types mentioned in response, it's default type should be `text`. If type values is present in response then the corresponding value should be assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following  solution:

```js
let inlineEntity = [];
const data = {
    "text": "Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our customer support page.",
    "inlineStyleRanges": [{
        "style": "BOLD",
        "offset": 12,
        "length": 20,
        "type": "style"
    }],
    "inlineEntityRanges": [{
        "type": "LINK",
        "offset": 83,
        "length": 16,
        "data": {
            "target": "_self",
            "url": "/index.htm"
        }
    }]
}

const MARKER = '||||';

function breakByRanges(ranges, text, tempString) {
    const result = [];
    ranges.forEach((styleRange) => {
        const { offset, length, type } = styleRange;
        const str = text.slice(offset, offset + length + 1);
        tempString = tempString.replace(str, MARKER);
        result.push({ data: str, type });
    })

    return { result, tempString };
}

function breakData(data, ranges) {
    const { inlineStyleRanges, inlineEntityRanges, text } = data;
    const result = [];
    let tempText = text;
    let { result: styleResult, tempString: styleTempText } = breakByRanges(inlineStyleRanges, text, tempText);
    tempText = styleTempText;
    result.push(...styleResult);


    let { result: entityResult, tempString: entityTempText } = breakByRanges(inlineEntityRanges, text, styleTempText);
    tempText = entityTempText;
    result.push(...entityResult);

    let orderNumber = 0;
    const textItems = tempText.split(MARKER).map((data, index) => {
        if (result[index]) {
            result[index].order = orderNumber + index + 1;
        }
        const resultData = { data, type: 'text', order: orderNumber + index };
        orderNumber += 1;
        return resultData;
    });
    result.push(...textItems);
    return result.sort((first, second) => first.order - second.order).map((item) => ({ data: item.data, type: item.type }));
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(breakData(data)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but only issue is the order, it is missing in your solution. `{"data":"customer support ","type":"LINK"}`, should come before `{"data":"page.","type":"text"}`

Comment: I've made changes to the example, try it out.

Comment: Sorry just now found that, Link is missing the data property?  `link` & `target`.

Comment: Is it my fault?

Comment: I got an issue while implementing ur solution, In I got multiple entries in `inlineStyleRanges` breaking not working.  Please refer this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gofkkt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservice%2Fgenerate-inline-tags.service.ts

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, which is an adaptation of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54889207/1243641) to your previous question, merging the helper functions into the main one and updating to the new combined input format is this:

```js
const breakData = (data) => {
  const nodes = (data.inlineStyleRanges || [])
    .concat(data.inlineEntityRanges || [])
    .sort(({offset: o1}, {offset: o2}) => o1 - o2)
  const str = data.text || ''
  const indices = [
    0, 
    ...nodes.reduce((a, {offset, length}) => [...a, offset, offset + length], []),
    str.length
  ]

  const slim = ({offset, length, data, ...rest}) => ({...rest, ...data})

  return indices.slice(1).map((x, i) => [indices[i], x])
    .map(([a, b]) => str.substring(a, b))
    .map((s, i) => i % 2 == 0 
      ? {data: s, type: 'text'}     
      : {data: s, ...slim(nodes[(i - 1) / 2])}
    ).filter(({data}) => data.length > 0)
}

const data = {"text": "Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our customer support page.", "inlineEntityRanges": [{"data": {"target": "_self", "url": "/index.htm"}, "length": 16, "offset": 83, "type": "LINK"}], "inlineStyleRanges": [{"length": 21, "offset": 12, "style": "BOLD", "type": "style"}]}

console.log(breakData(data))
```

It returns more data per node than your request, including the `style`, `url`, and `target` nodes.  (There was one oddity in this: I brought the `url` and `target` nodes up a level because their parent node was `data` which conflicted with the `data` in the output; I don't particularly like this.  If you would be happy with `text` in the output node instead of `data`, then you could replace it in the ternary, and use this for `slim`: `({offset, length ...rest}) => ({...rest})`)

If you don't want this extended behavior, you can change it by replacing

```
      : {data: s, ...slim(nodes[(i - 1) / 2])}
```

with this:

```
      : {data: s, type: nodes[(i - 1) / 2].type}
```

(at which point you can also remove `slim`.)

That might be what you want to do, but the version as I wrote it keeps all sorts of information that might be useful downstream.

---

(One silly thing: the "text"/"style"/"LINK" capitalization differences really bothers some OCD part of me I didn't know I had.  For heaven's sake, change that to "link".  ;-)  )